# How can I implement fadeOut on my audios in the current Flutter audioplayers plugin version: ^3.0.1?

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I have the dart code however in the current version of the Flutter Audioplayers 3.0.1 plugin it reports error:

Error: The method 'fadeOut' isn't defined for the type 'AudioPlayer'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fadeOut'.

How can I implement a fade out in the current plugin version?

The code below shows the function I'm using:

```
void applyFadeOut(AudioPlayer player) {
  var _duration = Duration(seconds: 3);
  player.fadeOut(
    Duration(
      milliseconds: _duration.inMilliseconds,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to generate the following code to make a fadeOut:

```
for (var i = 1.0; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1) {
  await Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 200)); //2 seconds
  player.setVolume(i);
}
```